# SWIFT: Troubles Modifying Some Parse Columns/ For Some Users. != ACL

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

To start this is not an ACL issue. 
I am having troubles adding and removing objects to some users this way: 
PFUser.currentUser()!["Key"].addObject(object)
  etc... and actually any other way present in Parse documentation.
To make the problem clearer, I have several users in Parse and I can modify only one column of this one user. The other columns, with all similar attributes, are not responding to my requests, even though I only change the key from the one that works. Furthermore, for this same column that works for one user, doesnt work for the other...
I am weirded out. Anyway, I was wondering if anyone has ever encountered such issue. I have conducted several hypotheses but none revealed correct.
Any help would be acclaimed and welcomed with wide open arms.
Thank you for your time.
Viktor

Comment: you get all of your user instances with PFUser.currentUser() right ?

Comment: How do you make your tests ? You have different devices to test more users ? Do you remove the app each time otherwise ? Because PFUser is cached so maybe they don't have the values you see on parse actually.

Comment: only one device.  though I have copied my project, but i dont think that might be it.what do you mean "remove the app" ?

Comment: So your are disconnecting your user with parse logout function ? By remove the app I mean remove it when you are in the device Dashboard.

Comment: I think you are onto something. I do not. When switching on the app, it is connected as a user, and I then just log in as a different one.    But then, how can for this user, (the one where a column works) the other columns dont work ?

Comment: Show all your code, when and where are you saving and what is the response?

Comment: It is in my appDelegate, within the function didUpdateLocation. But I have tried it on other view controllers and the same happens.   I am currently away from my laptop and my project, I will post my codes as soon as I return.   Thank you very much for taking part.

Comment: Just try what I said, remove the app from dashboard, then rebuild and log your user. ;) Or refresh the cache from user (see my answer)

Comment: I definitely will. Thanks a million for the help. I ll let you know as soon as done.

Answer (score 0):

Try PFUser.currentUser()!.refresh() before trying to set or get values to see if it's not a cache issue.

Comment: It seems that refresh has been changed to "fetch()". It doesnt work. I am logging out the user from Parse every time and it does not solve it. The last suggested option is to remove my app from my Parse dashboard. I will get on that. I guess I will have to reset it all up then. Hopefully will work.    I ll update you. Thanks again for the suggestions.

Comment: I said Device dashboard, not parse. ;) But I don't think it will change if it's not a cache issue.

Comment: But don't forget you need to refresh the user if you want to access values you just added/removed

Comment: Hi again, none of those work. I think the problem is because I made duplicated copies of my project. I now have several almost identical project connected to Parse with the same ID etc...   Might create misleading to the exchange of data with the server ?

Comment: Problem solved. Can you believe it is "addObject(object)" that caused the problem. I have replaced PFUser.currentUser()["key"].addObject(object)    by     PFUser.currentUser().addObject(object, "Key")       and it worked.   Go figure why the first method worked for one user in one column though... Anyway, gave me a headache but all ends well.    Thank you infinitely for the help though. Good day to you.